# How to edit a private channel's message/post using telegram bot in python?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I manage a channel that give links/information to users. Every time I update the content of the channel I have to update index of the channel in a post (message) manually.

Please teach me how to update a telegram post using telegram bot in python. Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 0):

The Bot API provides the method [`editMessageText`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) that you can use to edit the text of a message. Every library that provides a wrapper for the Bot API should also provide a wrapper for this method (in every language, not only in Python).

Comment: Thank you. This library has no example so that I can not understand how to do it. I've been searching for 3 days but seem no workable way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the message id and use https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to make a workable example. I am new at this and can not understand the api without example. Thanks a lots!